# Efficient way to get last part of string only after a certain base string

Tags: php, substring

What is an efficient way to get the part of a string after the occurrence of a certain needle, **only** if that needle is at the start of the haystack. Similar to `strstr()`, but **excluding** the needle, and only when found at the beginning of the string.

If it isn't found, it should preferably return false.

I have the feeling I'm overlooking some very obvious PHP functions here, but I can't seem to think of them right now.

For example:

```
$basePath = '/some/dir/';

$result = some_function( '/some/dir/this/is/the/relative/part', $basePath );
/*
should return:
this/is/the/relative/part
*/

$result = some_function( '/fake/dir/this/is/the/relative/part', $basePath );
$result = some_function( '/pre/some/dir/this/is/the/relative/part', $basePath );
/*
last example has '/some/dir/' in it, but not at start.
should both preferably return:
false
*/
```

I'll be using this for a filesystem service that should act as a sandbox, and should be able to give out and take in paths, relative to the base sand box directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put more simply than the other examples:

```
function some_function($path,$base){
  $baselen = strlen($base);
  if (strpos($path,$base) === 0 && strlen($path)>$baselen)
    return substr($path,$baselen);
  return false;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://www.ideone.com/MhHMt)**

Alternate using [strncmp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strncmp.php), too: **[DEMO](http://www.ideone.com/VCkem)**

Comment: I like the `strncmp` variant very much!

Comment: PS.: the `strlen($path) > $baselen` on the `strncmp` variant is redundant, no? Or am I overlooking something vital here?

Comment: @fireeyedboy: I added the check in case the path matches the base. You'll receive a `false` back saying, basically, "i have no further information to grab".

Comment: Ah yes of course, clever! Although, in this case I don't mind it returning an empty string. As this would be a valid relative path. Good thinking though. Much brighter than I am today. :)

Comment: About your `strncasecomp()` remark. Good point! But seeing I'm dense today, I'll have to ponder on the implications of this first, before commenting any more. :) Thanks so far!

Answer (score 3):

This case calls for [strncmp](http://php.net/strncmp):

```
function some_function($path, $base) {
    if (strncmp($path, $base, $n = strlen($base)) == 0) {
        return substr($path, $n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the way to go. Thanks. Brad was a bit earlier with a very similar `strncmp` variant. But this one is a tad bit sleeker though. :D

Answer (score 1):

```
function some_function($haystack, $baseNeedle) {
   if (! preg_match('/^' . preg_quote($baseNeedle, '/') . '(.*)$/', $haystack, $matches)) {
      return false;
   }
   return $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function some_function($path, $basePath) {
    $pos = strpos($path, $basePath);
    if ($pos !== false) {
        return substr($path, strlen($basePath));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But what about this?

```
some_function('/base/path/../../secret/password.txt', '/base/path/safe/dir/');
```

You likely want to call `realpath()` on `$path` first, so that it is fully simplified, before using `some_function()`.

Comment: Good point about `realpath()`, but I'm using that already actually. Thanks!

Comment: @fireeyedboy: Though it's really on valid in a *nix environment. ;-) (Unless you switch to [strncasecmp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strncasecmp.php))

Comment: @Brad: not sure I follow you. Sorry, I'm a bit dense today. Do you mean to say `realpath()` is only valid on *nix? Because of case sensitivity perhaps?

Comment: @fireeyedboy: Actually, I'm the one slipping. :grin: The answers [min & erisco] were right below each other. I saw your reply to my answer and though I was replying back in the same post. D'oh! My original comment was in regards to *nix being case sensitive with paths (your reference to strncmp and my reply with strncasecmp). My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @erisco: `if ($pos !== false)` should actually be `if ($pos === 0)` in my case, because it should only be valid if the needle is found at the start of the haystack.

Comment: @Brad: no problem. I figured that might have been the case. Wasn't sure though. :) I will follow up under your answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a built-in function for this.

```
function some_function($str1, $str2) {
  $l = strlen($str2);
  if (substr($str1, 0, $l) == $str2)
    return substr($str1, $l);
  else
    return false;
}
```

For long `$str1` and short `$str2`, I think this is going to be faster than using `strpos`.

If you're using this for paths, you might want to do some checking if the slashes are at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

How about regular expressions?

```
$regexp = preg_quote($basepath, '/');
return preg_replace("/^$regexp/", "", $path);
```