# PHP file_put_contents with absolute path?

Tags: php, wordpress, absolute-path

I use Wordpress and PHP and the function file_put_contents(). Wordpress file structure can look different depending on the user.

I need to call it like this:

```
file_put_contents(TEMPLATEPATH . '/ps_logo2.png');
```

or the same thing like this:

```
file_put_contents('C:\wamp\www\domain\modehallen.se/wp-content/uploads/images/ps_logo2.png');
```

The case above is the absolute path on localhost (that's why it's C:). I need the path or some other way to make sure the file is put in the right place.

How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`realpath()` will tell you if it is a valid path in the filesystem. To test if the path is actually in a given 'sandbox' path, see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342185/efficient-way-to-get-last-part-of-string-only-after-a-certain-base-string) I asked here recently.

Comment: Or did I misinterpret your question?

Comment: It helped me solve the problem. It returned nothing at first and that helped me find out that the folder to put the contents in was not created. It needs to be created first.

Comment: @Jens: ok, you may also want to look at `file_exists()` which actually is intended for seeing if a file/dir exists. `realpath()` is a bit of a shortcut that expands paths to their real path equivalent, and returns `false` on failure, which most of the time would mean the path does not exist. I thought you might wanna know that too.

Answer (score 12):

How about something like:

```
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."path/to/user/wordpress/account/".TEMPLATEPATH.'/ps_logo2.png');
```

**edit**

`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` gives the path to the script currently being processed.